# SQL/ACCESS Get Value From Previous Row

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

Ok, so sweet and short. I'm writing a Forms App in VB and I'm connected to an ACCESS file. I need to get the value from the first select statement and use it in the second select statement. I know I can do this through the application itself but I'm looking to do it this way. Thanks in advance.

```
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(
        "SELECT SSClass AS result
        FROM Members 
        WHERE Names = '" + lstBoxMembers.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'
        UNION 
        SELECT Names FROM Members WHERE SSClass= result ", conn)
```

Comment: Why did you add mysql and oracle tags?

Comment: why would you not create a derived table or even a subquery

Comment: Subquery would work for Access

Comment: Why are you using UNION? Why don't you include SSClass as a column of the listbox then reference that value from the selected item? Not sure how vb.Net would do it but in VBA it would be like: `"SELECT Names FROM Members WHERE SSClass = '" & lstBoxMembers.Column(1) & "'"`. Otherwise, possibly: `"SELECT Names FROM Members WHERE SSClass IN (SELECT SSClass FROM Members WHERE Names = '" & lstBoxMembers.SelectedItem.ToString() + "')"`